# Java Socket/P2P questions

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm learning about java sockets in a class of mine. I'm having issues with the communication between the peers. My question is why am I receiving this exception:
Exception java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused: connect

for example:

in my main thread

```
    ServerSocket listenSock = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(argv[2]),0,InetAddress,getByName(null));

    //Create Server loop to process inbound connections
    while(true){
        //accept an incoming client by saving it to a socket to use to communicate with it
        Socket clientSock = listenSock.accept();

        /waa/create a thread to handle the inbound client  so that we can return to accept()
        InboundHandler inboundMsg = new InboundHandler(clientSock); // listens to the peers outbound socket
        Thread inThread = new Thread(inboundMsg);
        inThread.start();
        // add the peer to the list.
    }
```

in a seperate thread I have a

```
public InboundHandler(Socket socket) throws Exception{
    this.socket = socket; //save the socket object to "this" instance of the class
    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())); // listens from the clients speaking socket
}
public void run(){
    while(true){
    try{
        String line = input.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Could not read input. " + e);
    }    
    }
```

and finally I have a thread that sends out messages

```
for(int i=0;i<portList.size(); i++){
    if(nameList.get(i)!=Username){
        Socket peerSocket= new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(null),portList.get(i));
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(peerSocket.getOutputStream()));
        writer.write(Username + " has connected");
        writer.flush();
    }
    }
    }
    catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Some IO problem. " + e);
    }
```

My program compiles, and when I run it, I receive the Exception
java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused: connect

From what it's sounding like, is the port that my one peer is trying to speak to, isn't being heard by the other peers. But this is more guessing

As for the while(true) I am going to change that later, with a boolean statement.

Comment: `while(true)` will produce deadlocks - its basically what is considered "bad code" - at least outside of the hobbyist-community. If you get rid of it and exchange it for some meaningful, sensible variable-check you will prevent quite a few headaches.

Comment: also : nobody knows what your question is, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: How are you creating your ServerSocket?

Comment: Edited my post. I'm just wondering why I'm getting this Connection refused, as I believe I'm communicating to the correct ports. ServerSocket is created in my first block of code. I'm also going to store my Socket peerSocket as an array in later coding.(Not everything I have in inclusive, trying to keep it to the barebones)